# How can you create custom headers using Table function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have a data frame for each team that looks like `nebraska` below. However, some of these poor teams don't have a single win, so their `$Outcome` column has nothing but `L` in them.

```
> nebraska
           Teams     Away/Home   Score   Outcome
1     Arkansas State      Away    36 
2           Nebraska      Home    43        W
3           Nebraska      Away    35        L
4             Oregon      Home    42                          
5  Northern Illinois      Away    21                          
6           Nebraska      Home    17        L
7            Rutgers      Away    17                          
8           Nebraska      Home    27        W
9           Nebraska      Away    28        W
10          Illinois      Home     6                          
11         Wisconsin      Away    38                          
12          Nebraska      Home    17        L
13        Ohio State      Away    56                          
14          Nebraska      Home    14        L
```

When I run `table(nebraska$Outcome` it gives me my expected outcome:

```
table(nebraska$Outcome)
  L W 
7 4 3
```

However, for the teams that don't have a single win (like `Baylor`), or only have wins, it only gives me something like:

```
table(baylor$Outcome)
  L
7 7
```

I'd like to specify custom headers for the table function so that I can get have something like this output:

```
table(baylor$Outcome)
  L W
7 7 0
```

I've tried passing the argument `dnn` to the table function call, but it throws an error with the following code:

```
> table(baylor$Outcome,dnn = c("W","L",""))
```

> Error in names(dn) <- dnn : 
>          'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Can someone tell me how I can tabulate these wins and losses correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with(rle(sort(nebraska$Outcome)),
     data.frame(W = max(0, lengths[values == "W"]),
                L = max(0, lengths[values == "L"])))
#  W L
#1 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has to be that complicated. Just make `baylor$Outcome` a `factor` and then `table`. E.g.:

```
# example data
baylor <- data.frame(Outcome = c("L","L","L"))
```

Then it is just:

```
baylor$Outcome <- factor(baylor$Outcome, levels=c("","L","W"))
table(baylor$Outcome)

#  L W 
#0 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Following a `tidy` workflow, I offer...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- nebraska %>%
  group_by(Teams, Outcome) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread(Outcome, n) %>%
  select(-c(`<NA>`))

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   Teams [8]
#               Teams     L     W
# *             <chr> <int> <int>
# 1    Arkansas State    NA    NA
# 2          Illinois    NA    NA
# 3          Nebraska     4     3
# 4 Northern Illinois    NA    NA
# 5        Ohio State    NA    NA
# 6            Oregon    NA    NA
# 7           Rutgers    NA    NA
# 8         Wisconsin    NA    NA
```

...and I couldn't help myself but to pretty with `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra`

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

[image]